# Stored procedure never deletes rows when called

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Inside a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure, I have the following lines of code that do the following:

- Declares and sets a variable called `@galaxyID`
- Then uses that `@galaxyID` to delete all rows from a table called `galaxyObjects` that have a particular `galaxyID`

I need to check to make sure that `@galaxy` is not null because sometimes the column is NULL in the table `astroList`.

I don't have any errors, but nothing is ever deleted and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @galaxyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SET @galaxyID = (SELECT galaxyID FROM astroList WHERE astroID = @astroID)

DELETE FROM galaxyObjects 
WHERE galaxyID = @galaxyID AND @galaxyID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Does the adhoc `select` with these criteria return anything?

Comment: Hi @PeterSmith ! What is a adhoc select?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - just run the embedded `select` on its own. Okay?

Comment: @PeterSmith there are rows in astroList that are NULL.  In galaxyList, there are a few rows that have a NULL galaxyID.

Comment: Aside: You might want to get `@galaxyID` and then `if @galaxyID is not NULL delete from galaxyObjects where galaxyID = @galaxyID;`.

Comment: Hi @HABO isn't that what I'm doing?  Or do I need to rewrite it?  thanks! :)

Comment: The net effect is the same, but it seems a bit clearer (to me) if you simply skip the `delete` when it isn't needed rather than hiding that at the tail end of the `where` clause.

Comment: @HABO Would I need to do IF(@galaxyID IS NOT NULL) BEGIN DELETE END

Comment: [`If`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says you can have a `Boolean_expression` and a `sql_statement` or `statement_block`. If you get paid by the token then go for it: `begin if ( ( @galaxyID ) is not NULL ) begin delete from galaxyObjects where ( ( galaxyID ) = ( @galaxyID ) );;; end;; end;` with extra statement terminators ought to get extra credit. Unfortunately you can't add parentheses around `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *really* use `SET @var = (SELECT ...)` unless there is **no possible way** for the `SELECT` to ever return more than one row. So anyone looking at this code that doesn't know the data model will assume this is a ticking time bomb. A safer option in SQL Server is to use a `DELETE` with a join (which works for any number of rows, and is a no-op when there is no match):

```
DELETE go
  FROM dbo.astroList AS al
  INNER JOIN dbo.galaxyObjects AS go
  ON al.galaxyID = go.galaxyID
  WHERE al.astroID = @astroID;
```

This will ignore rows where `galaxyID` in `astroList` is NULL.

Comment: If I can't use SET then how do I get the @galaxyID

Comment: Why do _you_ need the `@galaxyID`? You just need to delete the rows from `galaxyObjects`, right? If you _want to see_ what rows were affected, you could use the `OUTPUT` clause, but this is kind of like ordering a hamburger - you want the hamburger, you don't need to check which box the frozen burger came out of before it is made, you just want the end result. If the only point of you obtaining the `@galaxyID` was to then pass it to the `DELETE` statement, the whole point of my answer is so you can eliminate that unnecessary step.

Comment: The table astroList has a column called galaxyID. When that column has a value, that means there is a corresponding row in galaxyObjects with that same galaxyID.  So I need to delete the row in galaxyObjects with that galaxyID.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I understand. That's what this code does. You don't have to put `@galaxyID` in a variable to delete rows based on the `galaxyID` another table.

Comment: Oh I think I see, so in your query, 'go' is the row in galaxyObjects that has a relationship with the row in astroList based on galaxyID?

Comment: `go` is an alias that references the table `galaxyObjects`. The script basically says, find all the rows in `galaxyObjects` that have the same _non-NULL_ `galaxyID` as the `galaxyID` in `astroList` that matches `@astroID`, and delete them from `galaxyObjects`. It may be clearer without aliases, but they make for much more readable code IMHO.